# Spark DataFrame to generate beta sample

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark Dataframe with two of its columns 'alpha' and 'beta'.

These columns have value of integer greater than or equal to.

I wanted to create another column in this dataframe with beta sample coming from these two cols.

I tried

```
df = df.withColumn('beta_sample', np.random.beta(F.col('alpha'), F.col('beta')))
```

However, this throws me error saying

> An error was encountered:
> setting an array element with a sequence.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "mtrand.pyx", line 1706, in mtrand.RandomState.beta
>
> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

I am yet to try converting my spark dataframe to pandas dataframe and try something like

```
df['beta_sample'] = np.random.beta(df['alpha'], df['beta'])
```

But I would like to be able to do this in without converting to pandas.
Is there way I could access each entry of the column accordingly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use numpy functions on Spark dataframes directly. You need to use a UDF:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import numpy as np

df2 = df.withColumn('beta_sample', F.udf(np.random.beta, 'double')('alpha', 'beta'))
```